# I'm having trouble animating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging

I have tried many solutions including asking ChatGPT, but it didn't fix it. This is a C# script for Unity 2d. The objective of this script is to change the sprite of whatever it's attached to. I am on Unity version 2021.3.20f1. Here's the code:

```
    using System.Collections;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using UnityEngine;  
      
    public class Anims : MonoBehaviour  
    {  
        public Sprite sprite1;  
        public Sprite sprite2;  
      
        private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;  
    
        void Start()  
        {
            spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();  
        }  
      
        void Update()  
        {  
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))  
            {  
                // Set sprite to sprite1 (facing left)  
                spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite1;  
            }  
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))  
            {  
                // Set sprite to sprite2 (facing right)  
                spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite2;  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

I get the error

```
Assets\Scripts\Anims.cs(22,28): error CS1061: 'SpriteRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'sprite' and no accessible extension method 'sprite' accepting a first argument of type 'SpriteRenderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried to ask ChatGPT, but it did not fix the problem. Then I tried substituting some things and seeing if capitalization worked, but nothing seemed to fix it.

Comment: The error suggests that you're trying to call `sprite` as a method, i.e., `spriteRenderer.sprite()`, but the code you posted doesn't reflect this. Is your code saved in your IDE? If so, is this your full & complete script? Do you have any other errors that would prevent Unity from compiling this script?

Comment: This code is a C# script to be attached to an object letting it change it's sprite being shown upon pressing A and D. This code is saved in my Unity Folder, don't know what IDE is. This is the full script, and there are two errors, the one stated and another almost identical but for (27,28).

Comment: IDE = Integrated Development Environment. Do you have another script/class in your project called SpriteRenderer that might be hiding the SpriteRenderer inside the UnityEngine namespace? If you change all references of type `SpriteRenderer` to `UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer`, does it start working?

Comment: No worries at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have another script/class in your project called `SpriteRenderer`.

You can either refactor your `SpriteRenderer` class to another name (recommended) or explicitly use the one inside the UnityEngine namespace via `UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer`.